# Make Typescript infer the return value based on the passed props

Tags: typescript

Suppose the following:

```
interface IMyFunctionWithParam1 {
  param1?: boolean;
  param2?: never;
}
interface IMyFunctionWithParam2 {
  param1?: never;
  param2?: boolean;
}

type TMyFunction = IMyFunctionWithParam1 | IMyFunctionWithParam2;
const myFunction = ({ param1, param2 }: TMyFunction) => {
  if (param1) {
    return {
      hello: 'world'
    };
  }

  if (param2) {
    return {
      goodbye: 'world'
    };
  }

  return null;
}

const result1 = myFunction({ param1: true }); // { hello: 'world' }
const result2 = myFunction({ param2: true }); // { goodbye: 'world' }
const result3 = myFunction({}); // null
```

Here, we can say that `myFunction` accepts only either `param1` or `param2` as possible props. The return value of `myFunction` is:

```
{
    hello: string;
    goodbye?: undefined;
} | {
    goodbye: string;
    hello?: undefined;
} | null
```

How can I ensure that Typescript knows that `result1` is of type,

```
{
    hello: string;
    goodbye?: undefined;
}
```

Comment: In TypeScript, it usually complicates things a fair bit when types are empty other than optional properties, is that really the case or do the interfaces really have other, non-optional properties (presumably common ones)? If they don't, two separate functions would seem more appropriate.

Comment: They do, I kind of slimmed down my use case for the purposes of this question

Comment: You'll need to make `myFunction` either generic or overloaded, neither of which will actually properly check that the implementation matches the intended call signature(s).  For generics this issue is [ms/TS#33014](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014) and for overloads it is [ms/TS#13235](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13235). So you'll need to loosen types in the function, such as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NBd8kW). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @MikeK - I suspected so. :-) When you do that, it's best to leave at least *one* of the common properties in, since it can matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try out the following approach to narrow down the return types individually, which utilizes TS type generics and conditional types:

```
interface IMyFunctionWithParam1 {
    param1?: boolean;
    param2?: never;
}
interface IMyFunctionWithParam2 {
    param1?: never;
    param2?: boolean;
}

type Param = "Param1" | "Param2" | null;
// Using conditional types below
type TMyFunction<P extends Param> = P extends "Param1"
    ? IMyFunctionWithParam1
    : P extends "Param2"
        ? IMyFunctionWithParam2
        : null;
type MyFunctionReturnType<P extends Param> = P extends "Param1"
    ? { hello: string; goodbye?: string }
    : P extends "Param2"
        ? { hello?: string; goodbye: string }
        : null;

const myFunction = <P extends Param>(params?: TMyFunction<P>): MyFunctionReturnType<P> => {
    if (params?.param1) {
        return {
            hello: "world"
        } as MyFunctionReturnType<P>;
    }
    if (params?.param2) {
        return {
            goodbye: "world"
        } as MyFunctionReturnType<P>;
    }
    return null as MyFunctionReturnType<P>;
};

const result1 = myFunction<"Param1">({ param1: true }); // TS will infer return type as { hello: string; goodbye?: undefined; }
const result2 = myFunction<"Param2">({ param2: true }); // TS will infer return type as { hello?: undefined; goodbye: string }
const result3 = myFunction<null>(); // TS will infer return type as null
```

To find more information about Conditional Types and Type Generics, check out the links below:

- [Type Generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html)
- [Conditional Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html)